# Embed shortcodes and oEmbed not working on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, youtube, oembed

I am having a weird issue.

Normally when you paste a youtube video the video will embed properly automatically. However when I paste a link into the visual view I can play and see the embedded video in the EDIT view, but on preview or publish it echoes out the link without embedding it as plain text.

So far I have tried disabling all plugins (except Advanced Custom fields)
Using the [embed] shortcode
Changing the youtube links from http to https

What does work is pasting the embed code from Youtube, or writing `<iframe>` in the text view.
It also works fine to paste and embed when I change theme

Comment: "It also works fine to paste and embed when I change theme". It seems pretty clear that it's your theme what's preventing oEmbed from parsing Youtube links into video embeds. Check your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: Yeah I also thought this, but I don't know what I'm looking for in functions. I have added a whole load of custom image sizes and one custom post type but that's all i remember doing.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was I was using

```
<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
```

Instead of

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

As per the Wordpress Codex:

> An important difference from the_content() is that get_the_content()
> does not pass the content through the the_content filter. This means
> that get_the_content() will not auto-embed videos or expand
> shortcodes, among other things.

[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/#:~:text=An%20important%20difference%20from%20the_content()%20is%20that%20get_the_content()%20does%20not%20pass%20the%20content%20through%20the%20the_content%20filter.%20This%20means%20that%20get_the_content()%20will%20not%20auto%2Dembed%20videos%20or%20expand%20shortcodes%2C%20among%20other%20things](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/#:%7E:text=An%20important%20difference%20from%20the_content()%20is%20that%20get_the_content()%20does%20not%20pass%20the%20content%20through%20the%20the_content%20filter.%20This%20means%20that%20get_the_content()%20will%20not%20auto%2Dembed%20videos%20or%20expand%20shortcodes%2C%20among%20other%20things).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[video]` **short code** instead. It is incorporated in the Wordpress core nowadays. Go to this link for more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Video_Shortcode

For example:

```
[video width="640" height="360" src="/wp-content/uploads/files/movie.mp4"]
```

May this not work in a custom theme, then you want to look at how the content of the post is being processes. You may need to apply the `the_content` filter to the post content variable like this:

```
apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```